# App crashes when I press login button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, setcontentview

I'm trying to make this small app as a beginner, and in the first page I want to press the login button to go to the login page. I did some search and I used intent and my code has no errors. However, whenever I press the login button, the app crashes, and I don't know why. I tried my best to find out, and this is my last hope here.

Main Class:

```
package com.example.ali.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Loginpage.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Login Class:

```
package com.example.ali.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Loginpage extends ActionBarActivity    {

    Button b1,b2 , b3;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    TextView tx1;
    int counter = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }

        });

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tx1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&

                        ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    counter--;
                    tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

These are the xml files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and xml for login

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.test.Loginpage">

    <TextView android:text="Login" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff299f"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attempts Left:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="login"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: ^^ very difficult to help you without stack trace and error type etc.

Comment: 01-04 00:11:09.926    4272-4272/com.example.ali.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ali.test, PID: 4272
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ali.test/com.example.ali.test.Loginpage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)

Comment: i got something like that when i pressed th login button and it crashed

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `setContentView()` in your login activity and giving it the same layout file as your main activity. So you are probably getting a crash trying to set something in a view after calling `findViewById()` and it returned `null` because no view with that id exists in the main layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

in your **Loginpage** activty unstead of calling the same layout that you are using in your **MainActivity**

*activity_login : refer to the name of the layout of your **Loginpage** Activity

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to write the correct layout name in your **Loginpage.java** in `setContentView()` as you wrote the same layout name of **MainActivity.java**, so probably when the app tried to find the view id of the views you declared, it didn't found them, and they were considered as `null`.

Comment: I did change the setContentView() of my loginpage coreectly and stil crashes right when i press the button in the first main page

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is crashing when you push the button because you have no b3 in xml for login. Change this line in Loginpage to a button that exist:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
```

The crash occurs when loading the Loginpage class. To quickly see if that's the case rename R.id.b3 in the line above to R.id.button and test again.

You might also change this line in MainActivity (change back if it crashes :) ):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Loginpage.class);
```

to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Loginpage.class);
```

Larry Schiefer/minos23 answer is also needed in order not to crash (but you did this already).

Comment: no problem, if you think my answer helped you, consider an up-vote so a person with you problem quickly can find the correct answer. Have a nice evening.

Comment: yes i did i did but i need to earn more points to vote and stuff, still new here. Thanks and have a nice evening you too